# Manga where Mc is cheated by his wife and sent to another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I'm trying to remember this manga where the MC is cheated by his wife for another man and the MC is reincarnated by a "being" to another world where everything is advanced and becomes a ruler of a planet with a robot maid. The MC want's to abuse his power in his new life but the planet he rules is lacking, so he develops the planet in hope of becoming a villain that takes advantage of people weaker than him. The MC also learn swordsman ship from a mentor who half-heartly taught him. The "being" that reincarnated the MC is actually someone who enjoys seeing people suffer and is the one who ruined the MC's previous life by making his wife cheat on him

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like ***[I'm the Evil Lord of an Intergalactic Empire!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/g9ej9ao/oreaku-ore-wa-seikan-kokka-no-akutoku-ryoushu)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> In his last life, Liam lived as a moral, responsible person…but died deep in debt and betrayed by his wife. Reborn into the ruling family of a vast interstellar empire, Liam knows that life is divided between the downtrodden and the ones who do the stomping, so this time he’s going to take what he wants and live for himself. But somehow, things refuse to work out that way. Despite doing his best to become a tyrant, Liam’s decisions lead to nothing but peace and prosperity for the empire under his rule, and he just gets more and more popular!

The protagonist, Liam, was cheated on by his wife, and ends up alone, sick, and saddled with child support payments for a child that isn't his. He's subsequently visited by a mysterious being, who reincarnates him into the ruling family of an interstellar empire. He also has a robot maid named Amagi.

[image]

[image]